# jMonkeyEngine 3: Missing "Basic Game" Template for New Project?

Tags: java, macos, jmonkeyengine

I'm trying to create a new project in jme3 (on OSX) but the Basic Game template has disappeared from my menu. That is, I had it before because I definitely used the Basic Game template before, but now I can't find it anymore. It should be under File > New Project > JME3 > Basic Game, and it appears in all the tutorials and screenshots I've seen, but it's not showing up in mine:

[image]

I've tried deleting the application and redownloading and installing again but that didn't make a difference. Is there a way to get the template to show up again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved! Reinstalling the SDK isn't enough; the settings folder has to be deleted as well: http://wiki.jmonkeyengine.org/doku.php/sdk:troubleshooting (under Preferences and Settings). Works perfectly after that.